# What would cause FB like button to fail?

Tags: facebook

Facebook like button failing. The script displays the button, says i've liked it and increased the like count. But it displays nothing on my account and when I refresh the page it says i haven't. What would cause this?

Code: `<fb:like href="http://fbquote.me/like.php?id=<?php print $row['id']; ?>" send="false" layout="button_count"></fb:like>`

Comment: might have failed scraping for the OG meta tags :)

Comment: What's this url : http://fbquote.me/like.php?id=<?php print $row['id']; ?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's this url : `http://fbquote.me/like.php?id=<?php print $row['id']; ?>` ??

Do you use PHP ? Why do you use such a url ? Failing likes are often related to url errors

Also Do you load fb javascript ? 
Do you have something like

`<div id="fb-root"></div><script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>`

Somewhere in your page ?